# How to convert this SQL to LINQ or Lambda expression?

Tags: sql, linq, lambda

here's my sql query below:
Can you guys help me to convert this to a much cleaner one??

```
SELECT [PurchaseRequestID], [ProjectID],[FullName]
FROM PurchaseRequest
  WHERE [PurchaseRequestID] IN
    (SELECT [PurchaseRequestID] FROM PurchaseRequestDetail )
    AND [PurchaseRequestID] NOT IN
      (SELECT [PurchaseRequestID] FROM [PurchaseOrder] )
```

Though i have already converted this successfuly, i think this is not readable and needs to be rewritten:

```
var query = from a in db.PurchaseRequests
where
   (from b in db.PurchaseRequestDetails
    select new
    {
        b.PurchaseRequestID
    }).Contains(new { a.PurchaseRequestID }) &&
!(from c in db.PurchaseOrders
    select new
    {
        c.PurchaseRequestID
    }).Contains(new { a.PurchaseRequestID })
select a;
```

thanks

Comment: samantha07, I see you're new to this site. You have a couple of answers that work below. If you think one of them is your best answer, mark it as correct so others that come along can view what worked for you.

Comment: all of the answers work. too bad i can only pick 1. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = from a in db.PurchaseRequests
where
   db.PurchaseRequestDetails.Any(x => x.PurchaseRequestID == a.PurchaseRequestID) &&
   !db.PurchaseOrders.Any(x => x.PurchaseRequestID == a.PurchaseRequestID)
select a;
```

Answer (score 2):

you really don't need all those anonymous objects. Use the [let](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) keyword to introduce temporary variables instead of doing operations on the subqueries directly.

```
from a in db.PurchaseRequests
let b = from b in db.PurchaseRequestDetails select b.PurchaseRequestID
let c = from c in db.PurchaseOrders select c.PurchaseRequestID
where b.Contains(a.PurchaseRequestID) && !c.contains(a.PurchaseRequestID)
select a;
```

Comment: Cant see how that would work since a is of type `PurchaseRequests` and b and c are not. (Probably int)

Comment: ok. i changed it so it checks against `a.PurchaseRequestID`. now it should work. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

If you have navigation properties set up, you can write the query like this:

```
IQueryable<PurchaseRequest> query = 
  from purchaseRequest in myDataContext.PurchaseRequests
  where purchaseRequest.PurchaseRequestDetail.Any()
  where !purchaseRequest.PurchaseOrder.Any()
  select purchaseRequest;
```

Or this lambda/method style if you prefer...

```
IQueryable<PurchaseRequest> query2 = myDataContext.PurchaseRequests
  .Where(purchaseRequest => purchaseRequest.PurchaseRequestDetail.Any())
  .Where(purchaseRequest => !purchaseRequest.PurchaseOrder.Any());
```